# Can't adjust keyboard backlight on Asus ROG Strix G Laptop

Tags: keyboard, laptop, asus, brightness, backlight

I've looked at various guides and tools for adjusting the keyboard backlight brightness of my Asus G531GT laptop on Linux. All (e.g. https://github.com/iamweird/asus-kbd-backlight) seem to work by editing a configuration file for backlight brightness. The most common configuration folder is /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight.

However on my machine (with Pop OS/Ubuntu 19.04) I do not have such a folder. I do have /sys/class/leds with other subfolders, and I can use them to set the brightness of other leds on my machine, like the Caps Lock LED.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

If this [link](https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore) doesn't work try [this](https://github.com/JoshDreamland/rogauracore/archive/retool.zip) one.

After downloading and extracting it to the home folder
run these

```
cd rogauracore-retool
autoreconf -i
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Hope it works for you!!

To control

Usage:

```
sudo rogauracore COMMAND ARGUMENTS
```

Supported commands and usage:

```
single_static COLOR
single_breathing COLOR1 [COLOR2] [SPEED]
single_pulsing COLOR SPEED
single_colorcycle SPEED
multi_static COLOR1 COLOR2 COLOR3 COLOR4
multi_breathing COLOR1 COLOR2 COLOR3 COLOR4 SPEED
rainbow [SPEED]
brightness BRIGHTNESS 

red         lime        turquoise   blue        magenta     hotPink     
orange      green       cyan        indigo      pink        white       
yellow      teal        skyBlue     violet      deepPink    black
```

- `COLOR` argument(s) should be given as *color names*, or *hex values* like *ff0000*.
- `SPEED` argument should be given as *slow*, *medium*, or *fast*, or *integers 1 - 3*.
- `BRIGHTNESS` values should be given as *off*, *low*, *medium*, *high*, or *integers 0 - 3*.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered a project which allows to control the keyboard backlight for ROG laptops: https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore. After installing you can do `sudo rogauracore black` to turn off the backlight. You can also configure the lighting in similar ways to the Windows Aura Core software.

However I don't know whether the backlight can be dimmed with this project.

Answer (score 2):

```
rogauracore brightness 0
```

This is the only correct syntax.